# Grep keep (output) entire .txt file if one line contains string

Tags: text-processing, files, grep, cygwin

I know that

```
grep -rhI "# Active" > out.txt
```

will output any line containing `# Active` within the searched directory but I want the entire .txt file contents, so example

example.txt

```
Line1 
Line2
Line3 # Active
Line4
Line5
etc
```

So if I grep for `# Active` I want it to not just output the line containing `# Active` within these .txt file but all the other lines too, example

output.txt

```
Line1 
Line2
Line3 # Active
Line4
Line5
etc
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to use -C (context) switch for grep. Not ideal (need to know maximum lines in file), but helps.

Comment: What kind of line separator do you have between your lines? Windows (#10#13) or UNIX newlines (#13)? Maybe the whole file is treated as one line but displayed on multiple lines.

Answer (score 12):

For non-GNU versions of `grep`, which are unlikely to have `-z`, or if portability is required...

```
grep -q pattern file && cat file
```

`-q` suppresses any output but, per usual, exit status is set based on whether or not a pattern match was found. With a pattern match `grep` returns the success code `0` which is equivalent to *true* and that allows the `cat` command to be executed.

Comment: a variant :   `grep -l "pattern" ./file*s | xargs cat` . displays the (concatenated) entirety of all files that have at least 1 line matching "pattern"

Answer (score 10):

Normally, grep will just show the matching line:

```
$ grep -rhI "# Active"
Line3 # Active
```

To see the whole file, add the `-z` flag:

```
$ grep -rhIz "# Active"
Line1 
Line2
Line3 # Active
Line4
Line5
etc
```

`-z` is a GNU extension that tells grep not to use newline as the 'line' separator but to use a NUL character instead.  Since text files generally do not have NUL characters in them, this has the effect of telling grep to read the whole file as if it were a single 'line'.  Consequently, if there is a match, the whole file is printed.

On BSD/OSX versions of grep, the NUL input option is not available and `-z` means something else.

#### The other grep options

`-r` tells grep to search files and directories recursively.

`-I` tells grep to ignore binary files

`-h` tells grep to print the match without the filename attached.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` alternative:

```
sed -e 'H;1h;/PATTERN/!d;x;:do' -e 'n;b do' infile
```

this script works by accumulating lines in the `h`old buffer (and deleting them) until a matching line is encountered at which point it e`x`changes the buffers and executes `n` (i.e. print & get the next line) until there's no more input.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it on multiple files:

```
cat `grep -rIl "# Active" *`
```

Grep will return the list of filenames and cat will print them.

Comment: and pray that none of those paths contains spaces or other funky chars...

Comment: True, but this is the only way I see to do it with multiple files. If you have a solution to the "funky chars" feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: There are too many ways to do it right: use a `for` loop, use `find` with `-exec`, use `grep` with `-Z` and pipe it to `xargs -0 cat`, use `zsh` with `estring` qualifier etc...

Comment: `shopt -s globstar ; for file in **/*; do test -f "$file" && grep -qlF '# Active' "$file" && cat "$file"; done`

Comment: @don_crissti As I said, feel free to edit my answer